# $n$-point map $S$ from $k$-manifold $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

It is known that for every continuous map $M:S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ there are infinitely many double points. Also by the Borsuk-Ulam theorem, this is true for each continuous map $N:S^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
A question arising here concerns finding a (connected, metrizable) $k$-*manifold* $X$ for which each continuous map $S:X \to \mathbb{R}^k$ has a $n$-point, $2<n\in \mathbb{N}$.

**A:** Does there exist such $X$? and if yes then how it would be figured out?

**B:** Does there exist a minimal $X$? (means the number of $n$-points of a map $S:X \to \mathbb{R}^k$ be minimum among all $S$ and all $X$.)

**Note:** a function $f:X\to Y$ has a $n$-point if for some point $p\in Y$ the preimage $f^{-1}(\{p\})$ consists of **at least** $n$ -points in $X$; a $2$-point is also called a double point.